# LaTeX error: can't write file

Tags: errors, miktex

I'm using Miktex 2.9 on windows 7 x32, texniccenter as IDE. I encounter an error for a project that worked few days ago: when I compile, I get the message:

```
! I can't write on file `../preamble1.aux'.
```

The beginning of the .tex file is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\include{../preamble1}
\begin{document}
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the contents of `preamble1.tex`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why did you put `\include` in the preamble?

Please change to `\input`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I do not understand: few days ago, the \include worked fine... I upgraded from Miktex 2.8 to 2.9 (uninstall/reinstall), this might be the cause?

Comment: @Imsasu, I haven't seen `\include` in the preamble. Even though you use `\documentclass{book}`, you can use `\includeonly` only and not `\include` in the preamble. It is what I know. :-) If you feel my answer is the final solution, kindly mark it with green check :-)

Answer (score 12):

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-can-i-include-the-file-somedir-file-tex-in-the-file-somedir-subdir-anotherf/2214#2214) for an explanation of why `\input` works and why `\include` does not, why this has changed with recent tex distributions, and how to work around it for old documents, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the question directly, but one can get this same error for a different reason, and since this question is ranked first on google, I thought it might help others:

Note that you can also get this error if you try to create a file in a **subfolder that does not exists**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/252856)

Comment: @Miyase Oh, true, but it’s the first link that appears when googling this error, so I thought it might be useful to others as well.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't allowed and are usually deleted (for your information).

Comment: Sorry, I had several tabs open and mixed up two comments.