# Replacing openout_any=a pdflatex myfile.tex on Windows?

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX project with a rather complex document structure and obviously run into issues with `openout_any`. I've been reasoning that it's a bad idea to change that variable for LaTeX globally. On Linux I could run `openout_any=a pdflatex mydocument.tex` to apply it to that run only, however I'm actually using Windows (7), where that as far as I'm aware won't work. I already checked `pdflatex -help` and found no mention of a flag that would do any changes to `openout_any` for the run. Can anyone tell me a way to actually accomplish that short-time change?

Comment: you haven't said what system you are using, in texlive you could set openout_any in a texmf.cnf file (I have no idea about miktex) but it must surely be simpler for any specific document to write into the current directory and then move any files at the end, why do you need to write outside the current directory?

Comment: MiKTeX seems to require `MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES` rather than `openout_any` according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2214/19862) so you do need to specify whether you're using MiKTeX or TeX Live on Windows.

Comment: I'm using downloaded code from GitHub in my project. I basically understand how it works, but would prefer not to tinker with the structure just in case. As of the system, I do use TeX Live and already found out that `openout_any` should work. I also found out about the `texmf.cnf`, but would prefer not to apply security-relevant changes to the entire distribution. Also, I tried changing it for now as a workaround, and PDFLaTeX just straight up ignores the change for some reason.

Comment: This is not really a TeX question, rather it's a Windows question, lookup "Windows batch set environment variable" (assuming you're using batch (command prompt) instead of Powershell) I think the answer is `set openout_any=a` followed by (new line) `pdflatex <file...>`.

Comment: Side note: The question lost relevance to me personally, as I ended up not using that complex project. I'm not sure how much relevance this question has for others.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question because I wanted to know how to set openout_any from command line. So I describe my solution and an alternative way to achieve the desired result, here. So your question is part of my answer:

```
openout_any=a pdflatex ../../../source/latex/file.ins
```

can be used inside the `doc/latex/file` folder together with the following content in `docstrip.cfg`:

```
\BaseDirectory{../../..}
\UseTDS
```

At least with pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 this can be changed to the following command:

pdflatex --cnf-line=openout_any=a file.ins

A better solution would be to use point $TEXMFOUTPUT to a common a directory which contains all generated files. It can also be given on as parameter to the parameter `--cnf-line` and avoids changing `openout_any` at all. A complete shell script could be

```
#!/bin/sh -x
TEXMFOUTPUT="$(realpath ../../..)" 
cat >docstrip.cfg << EOF
\BaseDirectory{$TEXMFOUTPUT}
\UseTDS
EOF
pdflatex --cnf-line=TEXMFOUTPUT="${TEXMFOUTPUT}" file.ins
```

For batch scripts this would be similar.